# Android MediaPlayer - position skips around while buffering

Tags: java, android, media-player, motorola

I am experiencing a strange behavior while streaming music on some devices.  When the audio first starts playing, the position jumps around and plays erratically until the buffering has fully completed.

I began with the [sample code from Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm).
I am creating MediaPlayer in `OnCreate()` as such:

```
// Create Media Player
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
prepareMediaPlayer();
```

`prepareMediaPlayer` sets the data like this:

```
private void prepareMediaPlayer() {

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(myurl);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Playing sound",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and `onBufferingUpdate` prints out the buffer progress:

```
@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int bufferingProgress) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate() "+bufferingProgress + 
            "\ncurrentposition: "+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    seekbar.setSecondaryProgress(bufferingProgress);
}
```

And the log output I get shows how the position jumps around while the media player is still buffering.  I've tested on a few devices, and this only happens on a Moto G.  Is this a bug in the firmware or am I doing something wrong?

```
08-29 12:50:17.934 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 4
                                                                              currentposition: 0
08-29 12:50:17.934 277/com.test.mediaplayer D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-29 12:50:17.976 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 4
                                                                              currentposition: 0
08-29 12:50:18.014 27927-27945/com.test.mediaplayer V/RenderScript: 0xb7912ee8 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
08-29 12:50:21.414 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 8
                                                                              currentposition: 7
08-29 12:50:34.930 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 11
                                                                              currentposition: 9
08-29 12:50:50.085 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 15
                                                                              currentposition: 4
08-29 12:51:32.991 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 19
                                                                              currentposition: 2
08-29 12:53:25.036 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 22
                                                                              currentposition: 5
08-29 12:53:51.976 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 26
                                                                              currentposition: 1
08-29 12:56:26.004 27927-27946/com.test.mediaplayer I/MediaHTTPConnection: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
08-29 12:56:34.651 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 30
                                                                              currentposition: 10
08-29 12:56:35.862 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 33
                                                                              currentposition: 1102
08-29 12:56:38.211 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 37
                                                                              currentposition: 4
08-29 12:56:40.097 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 41
                                                                              currentposition: 9
08-29 12:56:43.034 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 44
                                                                              currentposition: 9
08-29 12:56:45.130 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 48
                                                                              currentposition: 3
08-29 12:56:49.841 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 52
                                                                              currentposition: 8
08-29 12:56:52.500 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 55
                                                                              currentposition: 8
08-29 12:56:55.748 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 63
                                                                              currentposition: 7
08-29 12:56:57.080 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 74
                                                                              currentposition: 1223
08-29 12:56:59.072 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 81
                                                                              currentposition: 979
08-29 12:57:00.073 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 81
                                                                              currentposition: 1979
08-29 12:57:03.596 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 88
                                                                              currentposition: 5
08-29 12:57:05.862 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 92
                                                                              currentposition: 4
08-29 12:57:08.291 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 95
                                                                              currentposition: 8
08-29 12:57:13.903 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 99
                                                                              currentposition: 9
08-29 12:57:14.904 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 100
                                                                              currentposition: 668
08-29 12:57:34.261 277/com.test.mediaplayer V/audio-player: onBufferingUpdate() 100
                                                                              currentposition: 224068
```

Comment: Why setOnPreparedListener is called two times on the same mediaPlayer instance? First time in onCreate() method, like `mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this)`, and then in prepareMediaPlayer() method you are creating and setting a new one `mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()`.

Comment: @StasysSkliutas You're right, the first `setOnPreparedListener` was a mistake.  I removed it, but the result has not changed.

Comment: Some additional information would be helpful. On which android version code ran successfully?, on which version of android the code failed? What is the source of the stream, I assume from the code, that it is a remote resource? Does this behavior happen for any file, for instance song1.mp3, song2.mp3, ... or just for one particular file?

Comment: At what point in all that is the prepared listener called? It may be helpful to see a log from that callback.

Comment: @StasysSkliutas This error happens for all remote source files that I have tried.  The Moto G, on which the error occurs, is running Android 6.0.1.  Other phones, including emulators, that I have tried, do not experience this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a note related to this in the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> There is a subtle but important difference between a newly constructed MediaPlayer object and the MediaPlayer object after reset() is called. It is a programming error to invoke methods such as getCurrentPosition() ... in the Idle state for both cases

It also adds:

> It is important to note that the Preparing state is a transient state, and the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined.

It seems it is not safe for you to call `getCurrentPosition()` until after the `onPrepared` callback. The solution is probably to pause the playback while buffering.

Comment: Good information, but even when I remove the log line which calls `getCurrentPosition()`, it still plays erratically.  The MediaPlayer does not start playing until `mediaPlayer.start()` in the `onPrepared` listener, so nothing is called when in the Preparing or Idle state.

Comment: So you're seeing the thumb jump, or hearing the audio? Do you have a sample app somewhere?

Comment: Both the thumb and the audio jump. The link to the sample code is in the question, the only code I added is shown above.